# Does Tor really use only one exit node for one website or more than one in the background?

Tags: exit-relays

In current Tor design, everytime a user type in an URL1, TBB will connect with that URL1 using a Tor path (say, A-B1-C1, with C1 is an exit node). And, for another URL2, TBB will connect with that URL2 using a Tor path A-B2-C2, wich C2 is another exit node.

So my question is that, if the website of URL1 has contents that link to website of URL2 (e.g., a video clip, or a picture), will TBB still use C1 to load those contents or will it use C2 in background to load the contents from URL2?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

It uses the "first party domain" to isolate requests (I.E. requests within a tab will use the same circuit, based on the domain in the tab).

If URL1 has some `<img src=URL2>` html entity, it should use C1 to fetch it, similarly if URL2 has some `<img src=URL1>` content, it should use C2 to fetch it.

Note that this doesn't *guarantee* different exits, just distinct circuits.

For more information see:

[#3455 (Tor Browser should set SOCKS username for a request based  on first party domain)](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/3455)

[Cross-Origin Identifier Unlinkability](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#identifier-linkability)